# Gelfand-Mazur theorem on $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: functional-analysis

Can we apply the Gelfand-Mazur theorem to the space $GL_n(\mathbb{C})\cup\{0\}$ with operator norm?

Comment: Do you mean the theorem on $C^*$-algebras that are fields?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Probably not, I mean the one that says: Division commutative complex Banach algebras are isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I think I've managed to verify all the assumptions (submultiplicativity comes from the properties of the op. norm, $||I||=1$, it is a vector space). Though, I couldn't find this simple result anywhere, so I'm asking here where is the catch.

Comment: Well, fields are commutative division algebras... In any case, $GL_n(\Bbb C)\cup\lbrace 0\rbrace$ isn't an algebra.

Comment: Why not? My definition of complex algebra is that it is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with multiplication.
In my first comment, the word "commutative" is redundant, it was a mistake.

Comment: It's simply not a vector space.

Comment: Why is that, please?

Comment: Take $i\neq j$, then $I+E_{ij},-I\in GL_n(\Bbb C)$ yet their sum, $E_{ij}$ is neither invertible nor zero.

Comment: I see:) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we can't ($GL_n(\mathbb{C})\cup\{0\}$ is not a vector space).